# ExtJS Line chart fill upperside

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, charts, dashboard

I need information about ExtJS Line chart custom style. I have refer this [example](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/docs/Ext.chart.series.Line.1/) and create chart successfully.
[image: Line Chart]

My question is, it possible to fill area of upper side of line instead of downward?

Please refer image for understanding.

[image: Expected...]

Any help and suggestion will great help for me.Thanks